# JQuery Mobile page breaks randomly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

http://dugley.com/checkin/

It breaks randomly sometimes it work, sometimes it doesn't. What's wrong with it?

Here's my Code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8" />
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1 user-scalable=0" />
                   <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
            <script src="my.js">
            </script>    
        </head>
        <body>
            <!-- Home -->
            <div data-role="page" id="one">
                <div data-theme="c" data-role="header">
                    <h3>Friends School</h3>
                </div>
                <div data-role="content" style="padding: 15px">
                    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                     <input type="submit" id="selectbutton" data-theme="b" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right" value="Choose Name" />
                    </div>
                    <input type="submit" id="button" data-theme="a" data-icon="alert" disabled="disabled" data-iconpos="top" value="Check-In" />
        <small style="display: none;">Not activating? Try going closer to the Upper School office. If still not working just go to the office and check-in manually</small> 
                </div>
       
            </div>
      <div data-role="page" id="two" data-theme="a">
       <div data-theme="c" data-role="header">
                    <h3>Select Name</h3>
                </div>
                <div data-role="content" data-theme="a">
       <ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder="Search people..." data-filter-theme="d"data-theme="d" data-divider-theme="d">
        <li data-role="list-divider">A</li>
        <li><a name="personname" href="#">Adam Kinkaid</a></li>
        <li><a name="personname" href="#">Alex Wickerham</a></li>
        <li><a name="personname" href="#">Avery Johnson</a></li>
        <li data-role="list-divider">B</li>
        <li><a name="personname" href="#">Bob Cabot</a></li>
        <li data-role="list-divider">C</li>
        <li><a name="personname" href="#">Caleb Booth</a></li>
        <li><a name="personname" href="#">Christopher Adams</a></li>
        <li><a name="personname" href="#">Culver James</a></li>
        <li data-role="list-divider">D</li>
        <li><a name="personname" href="#">David Walsh</a></li>
        <li><a name="personname" href="#">Drake Alfred</a></li>
        <li data-role="list-divider">E</li>
        <li><a name="personname" href="#">Elizabeth Bacon</a></li>
        <li><a name="personname" href="#">Emery Parker</a></li>
        <li><a name="personname" href="#">Enid Voldon</a></li>
        <li data-role="list-divider">F</li>
        <li><a name="personname" href="#">Francis Wall</a></li>
        <li data-role="list-divider">G</li>
        <li><a name="personname" href="#">Graham Smith</a></li>
        <li><a name="personname" href="#">Greta Peete</a></li>
        <li data-role="list-divider">H</li>
        <li><a name="personname" href="#">Harvey Walls</a></li>
        <li data-role="list-divider">M</li>
        <li><a name="personname" href="#">Mike Farnsworth</a></li>
        <li><a name="personname" href="#">Murray Vanderbuilt</a></li>
        <li data-role="list-divider">N</li>
        <li><a name="personname" href="#">Nathan Williams</a></li>
        <li data-role="list-divider">P</li>
        <li><a name="personname" href="#">Paul Baker</a></li>
        <li><a name="personname" href="#">Pete Mason</a></li>
        <li data-role="list-divider">R</li>
        <li><a name="personname" href="#">Rod Tarker</a></li>
        <li data-role="list-divider">S</li>
        <li><a name="personname" href="#">Sawyer Wakefield</a></li>
       </ul> 
                </div>  
      </div><!-- /page two -->
            <script>
            
             var tries = 0;
                function check(){
        //alert('d');
        
        if(tries>4){
         first=true;
         $("small").fadeIn(3000);
         //alert("In")
        }
        else{
         $("small").fadeOut(3000);
        }
        
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition( function(loc){
         var lat1 = 39.35691630053478;
         var lon1 = -76.62641812613514;
         //var lat1 = 39.4354312;
         //var lon1 =  -76.6642454;
         var lat2 = loc.coords.latitude;
         var lon2 = loc.coords.longitude;
         var radlat1 = Math.PI * lat1/180
         var radlat2 = Math.PI * lat2/180
         var radlon1 = Math.PI * lon1/180
         var radlon2 = Math.PI * lon2/180
         var theta = lon1-lon2
         var radtheta = Math.PI * theta/180
         var dist = Math.sin(radlat1) * Math.sin(radlat2) + Math.cos(radlat1) * Math.cos(radlat2) * Math.cos(radtheta);
         dist = Math.acos(dist)
         dist = dist * 180/Math.PI
         dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515
        
         if(dist < 0.06){
          $('#button').button('enable'); 
          tries = 0;
          //$( "#button" ).text("Check-In");
          $('#button').buttonMarkup({ icon: "star" });
         }
         else{
          //$("#button" ).text("Not on campus.");
          tries += 1;
          $('#button').button('disable'); 
          $('#button').buttonMarkup({ icon: "alert" });
         }
         //alert(dist);
         
    
        });
        
        $('#button').button('refresh');
       }
      var id = setInterval("check()",2000);
      $( "#button" ).bind( "click", function(event, ui) {
       $('#button').buttonMarkup({ icon: "check" });
       $('#button').button('disable'); 
       $( "#button" ).text("Checked in.");
       $('#button').button('refresh');
       window.clearInterval(id);
       //$.mobile.changePage("#two", "flip", true, false);
      });
      $( "#selectbutton" ).bind( "click", function(event, ui) {
       //alert('d');
       $.mobile.changePage("#two", "slide", true, false);
      });
      $( "[name=personname]" ).bind( "click", function(event, ui) {
       //alert($(this).html());
       $("#selectbutton").prop('value', $(this).html());
       $('#selectbutton').button('refresh');
    
       $.mobile.changePage("#one", "slide", true, false);
    
       
      });
    
            </script>
      
    
        </body>
    </html>
```

What's the problem with this, sometimes it works sometimes it doesn't.

Yet it works on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5e4ue/

I tried it out on two different domains on the same server and sometimes it works on one but not the other with same server code.
Comes out like 
[image: On iPhone]

Comment: have you looked into ur css file it's all chinese

Comment: Better if you download and host it yourself

Comment: http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css looks like it's in plain english..

Comment: it depends on yor browser decoding for some reason my turned to utf-16

Comment: in the link set charset to utf-8
`<link charset="UTF-8" /> ` should fix it

Comment: Look at dugley.com/checkin now. Changed it but not fixed.

Comment: well I'ts working great for me now and i've tried a couple of phones now

Comment: Works on my iPhone but not on my mac with Chrome.. Weird

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok for some reason your site sends out the `header` as `utf-16` which breaks your css file
try adding this to your `.html` file:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
```

And this to your `css` file link tag

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css" charset="UTF-8"/>
```

If you are server side programming (for e.g. php) you could use:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

As a last resort, make sure your file gets saved as `utf-8` in whatever editor you're using.  Check the documentation on how to do that; most often it can be set in document settings or preferences.

**Edit:**
if nothing works best thing would be to host the file yourself because at the end that's where the problem is.